# time complexity of function in terms of Big-O notation?

Tags: c++, algorithm

1) Althoug i have studied about the big O notation i couldn't understand how we calculate the the time complexity of this function in terms of Big-O notation. Can you explain in detail.

2) For recursive function; why we call len-2 while using  recursive function ?

```
bool isPalindrome( char *s, int len) {
             if (len <= 1) {
             return true;
        }
             else
            return ((s[0] == s[len-1]) && isPalindrome(s+1,len-2));
        }
```

What is the time complexity of this function in terms of Big-O notation?

```
T(0) = 1 // base case
T(1) = 1 // base case
T(n) = 1 + T(n-2)// general case
T(n-2)=1+T(n-4)
T(n) = 2 + T(n-4)
T(n) = 3 + T(n-6)
T(n) = k + T(n-2k) ... n-2k = 1  k= (n-1)/2
T(n) = (n-1)/2 + T(1)  O(n)
```

Comment: Advance start location by 1 char, decrease end location by 1 char (because they matched or it is not a palindrome) - difference is 2 characters in length. An alternative function signature might be `bool isPalindrome( char *start, char *end )`.

Comment: Pretty sure this would be O(n) as it is calling itself related to the length of the string.

Comment: ***What*** don't you understand about the calculation of O(n) ?

Comment: @phant0m how we write T(0) and T(1) base case and how we write the general case ? and also why we have 2 base case

Comment: you don't need do differentiate between the two base cases, as they are the same (see comment below me. I was wrong about this). The general case states how long an evaluation of length n takes. As long as an evaluation of length n-2 and 1 additional operation which is comparing two letters.

Comment: @RonnyBrendel Yes you do, otherwise it does not follow that the recursion terminates from the equations.

Comment: the book "introduction to algorithms" explains this very very well. Including e.g. how to work out the Recurrence (T(n)=...), O-Notation, Master-Theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call the recursive function with len-2 because in each execution you remove 2 characters from the word(the first and last). Hence len-2.
T(n) = 1 + T(n-2) = 1 + 1 + T(n-4) = 1 + 1 + 1 + T(n-6) = n/2 + T(1) = O(n)
A function g(n) is O(f(n)) if there exists a constant c and a number n0 so that for n>n0 
g(n) < c*f(n).
The big-O notation is just an upper limit, so that function is O(n) but also O(n^2) and so on.

Comment: How'd you come up with n^2?  It can only be called at most once per length - constant.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It's an *upper* bound ;)

Comment: @red_eyes You are using big O in a different way than I was taught. By my reckoning this algorithm is O(n), nothing else.

Comment: @john According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function. In the answer I also gave the formal definition of the notation. But probably the conventions differ and you defined it differently...

Comment: @red_eyes Things must have changed since I was at university.

Comment: @john It's just a detail. It is more accurate to say O(n), although it is not wrong to say O(n^2) or O(n^3). The most accurate notation we used in university is the big Theta notation(formal definition in that same wikipedia article). The big omega notation is the lower bound. So this function's complexity can be described as O(n), O(n^2), Omega(n), Omega(logn), Theta(n). All of the above are true.

Answer (score 1):

The function starts with a string of length n, and reduces it by 2 every time around the loop until it's all reduced away.

The number of iterations is therefore proportional to the length/2, ie `O(n/2)` => `O(n)`.